# Why is my fillpolygon shape looking odd (Java GUI)?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to make a black polygon with 8 points and put it in the center underneath the button. I believe I did everything correctly, but the polygon looks partly smushed and not centered under the button. Could someone explain why it's not working properly?

My overriding panel to create the polygon.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class OwnJpanel extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        int[] xpoints = {10, 20, 25, 25, 20, 10, 5, 5};
        int[] ypoints = {10, 25, 20, 27, 37, 37, 27, 20};

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, 8);

   }
}
```

My main class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main{

    public Main(){

    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.getContentPane();
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(500,500);

    OwnJpanel oj1 = new OwnJpanel();
    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    JButton jb1 = new JButton("Click Once");

    //jf.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, oj1); (Attempted this to center the polygon but it continues to be stuck in the left corner

    oj1.add(jb1);
    jf.add(oj1);

    jf.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
       new main();
    }            
}
```

Lastly, is there a JButton with a cross over the button? So a crossed out button (Like X, over the current JButton "Click Once").

Comment: *"Lastly, is there a JButton with a cross over the button? So a crossed out button"* do you mean a "+" or "X"?

Comment: The button is under the control of the panels layout manager, so it is likely to put where ever the layout manager decides it should be .  What shape are you trying to create?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I mean the X. I am trying to create a black 8 point polygon.

Comment: That doesn't mean much, I can make a 8 point polygon of a banana...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not sure what you mean by a black color filled in, enclosed polygon shape with 8 points and 8 edges.

Comment: Okay, but what's the shape "suppose" to be?  It's kind of a "blob" at the moment...

Comment: @MadProgrammer How would I not make it a blob with those coordinates given to create the polygon? It's supposed to look like this but with those coordinates as points: http://www.gilmerbaseball.org/images/tutorials/robin06.gif

Comment: Question rolled back to its original state and nonsense text removed. Please do not deface your question after it has received answers.

Answer (score 2):

First of all call `super.paintComponent(g);` in your method.

And don't use absolute coordinates. Define

```
int centerX=getWidht()/2;
int centerY=getHeight()/2;
```

Then use the center coordinates to adapt your drawing. e.g. centerX+something, centerY+something as coordinates.

Alternatively you can use g.drawString() passing "X" String and center the string.

Comment: how can I do so with those particular coordinates? I need to incorporate them to create that particular polygon. Also, how can I go about centering it right below the "Click Once" button?

Comment: Use the coordinates to center the polygon

Comment: So if I were to use super.paintComponent(g); along with g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, 8);, I should be able to create a Polygon with the xpoints and ypoints, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so instead of trying to figure out the relationship of the polygon to the button, which would take a quite a bit of work and would involve you having to be able to pre-calculate the required amount of space that the button AND the polygon would require, it would be simpler to "cheat" and make use of an appropriate layout manager to do the work for you...

You should also not rely on "magic" numbers and should rely on what is actually known at runtime, such as the actual width and height of the component

[image: Poly]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class PolyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PolyTest();
    }

    public PolyTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JButton btn = new JButton("A Button");
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(btn, gbc);
                frame.add(new PolyPane(), gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PolyPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.translate(5, 5);
            int width = getWidth() - 10;
            int height = getHeight() - 10;
            int x[] = new int[]{
                0, 
                width / 10, 
                width / 2, 
                width - (width / 10), 
                width, 
                width - (width / 4), 
                width / 4};
            int y[] = new int[]{
                height - (height / 3), 
                height / 5, 
                0, 
                height / 5, 
                height - (height / 3), 
                height, 
                height};
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawPolygon(x, y, x.length);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I realized that one of the provided coordinates was off, so I got the polygon shaped down. I attempted oj1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(oj1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); but why wouldn't that work? Isn't oj1 a panel? And what you've shown is that the easiest way to center the shape below the button? Seems very complex for what could be done in a few lines.

Comment: The default behaviour of `GridBagLayout`, when set up the way I have it, is to center the components.  So if I change the preferred size of my `PolyPane` to `200x200`, it will center them both together without you have to do any extra coding.  `BoxLayout` is another beast...

Comment: Could you edit your example with the following implementation? class OwnJpanel extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        int[] xpoints = {10, 20, 25, 25, 20, 10, 5, 5};
        int[] ypoints = {10, 25, 20, 27, 37, 37, 27, 20};

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, 8);

   }
}

Comment: Serious?  Why can't you replace the `int[] x` and `int[] y` lines with your requirements?  You do realise you will need to change the value returned by `getPreferredSize` and if the layout manager decides to provide your component with a different size, then all those wonderfully hard coded values will be worthless...